# What is the Correct Way To Add a :staging group to My Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler, gemfile

I have remotes set up on Heroku for production and staging.

On staging I have set the app's envs to include:

```
RACK_ENV=staging
RAILS_ENV=staging
```

I would like to be able to specify a `staging` group in my `Gemfile` in the same way I can currently use `production`, `test` or `assets`:

```
group :staging do
  gem "example", "~> 0.9"
end
```

I understand how to add custom groups. From my `application.rb`:

```
  groups = {
    assets: %w(development test)
  }
  Bundler.require(:security, :model, :view, *Rails.groups(groups))
```

**But how do I add a group that is only loaded in staging?**

I've tried without success:

```
  groups = {
    assets: %w(development test),
    staging: %(staging)
  }
  Bundler.require(:security, :model, :view, *Rails.groups(groups))
```

Comment: A bit off topic, but what is the benefit of having a separate gemfile for staging vs production?  Isn't the staging environment supposed to mimick the production one as closely as possible?

Comment: @tyler. I want some logging/debugging gear on staging that I don't want on production.

Comment: @Pedr maybe solve this problem by using production group, but using ```require: false``` to not require this logging gear when executing. And in staing.rb config place implicit require of this gear to enable it.

Comment: How about `Bundler.require(:staging) if Rails.env == :staging`?

Comment: I wanted to advise the same thing as @Waterlink already mentioned. I also did not quite get your groups logic in there. First of all, your code is not valid and secondly I don't understand what it should do.

Answer (score 11):

Your Gemfile could include a group as follows:

```
# Gemfile
  group :staging do
    gem 'example','~>1.0'
  end
```

Create an environment for staging

```
# /config/environments/staging.rb
... 
copy config/environments/production.rb code here with adjustments as needed
...
```

The reason this works is found in /config/application.rb.

Rails.groups includes the :default group (all ungrouped gems) and the gem group matching the name of the environment, set by RAILS_ENV, which in this case would be "staging". Your require. Your Bundler.require should look like:

```
Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))
```

For more info regarding Bundler and groups, read http://bundler.io/v1.5/groups.html